# Explain this relationship to me and prove it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $T: \mathbb{R}_{\leq 3}[X] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\leq 2}[X]$ be a linear map defined as $T(f(x)) = f'(x)$, and let $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be the standard ordered bases for resp. $\mathbb{R}_{\leq 3}[X]$ and $\mathbb{R}_{\leq 2}[X]$. Then the matrixrepresentation of the linear map is given as \begin{align*} A = [T]_{\beta}^{\gamma} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}. \end{align*} Let $\phi_{\beta}: \mathbb{R}_{\leq 3}[X] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ and $\phi_{\gamma}: \mathbb{R}_{\leq 2}[X] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be linear maps that represent de coordinates of the respective polynomials as columnvectors. We search a relationship between $L_A, \phi_{\beta}, \phi_{\gamma}$ and $T$, where $L_A$ is the left-multiplication transformation. Choose the polynomial $g(x)$, defined as $g(x) = 2 + x - 3x^2 + 5x^3 $. Then $\phi_{\beta} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ -3 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}$. Hence we have \begin{align*} L_A \circ \phi_{\beta} (g(x)) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ -3 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -6 \\ 15 \end{pmatrix}. \end{align*} Because $T(g(x)) = g'(x) = 1 -6x + 15x^2$, we have also \begin{align*} \phi_{\gamma}\circ (T(g(x))) = \phi_{\gamma} (g'(x)) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -6 \\ 15 \end{pmatrix}. \end{align*} So we can conclude that \begin{align*} L_A \circ \phi_{\beta} = \phi_{\gamma} \circ T. \end{align*} How should I understand this now? And how can I prove it in a rigorous manner? Some explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it is better to see how this relatin holds by looking at general case. I'll try to make similar notation.

1. When you have linear transformation $F$ from $R^n$ to $R^m$ then there exists exactly one matrix $A\in M(n\times m)$ such that $Fx$=$Ax.$ And $A_{i}^j=F^j(e_i),$ where $F^j(x)$ is a scalar from formula $F(x)=\Sigma_{j=1}^m F^j(x)e_j$
2. Similarly. When $A\in M(n\times m),$ then there exist exactly one linear transformation $L_A$ from $R^n$ to $R^m$ such that $L_{A}v$=$Av.$ And $L_A$ is just a left multiplication transformation.
3. If $V$ is a vector space of dimention $n$ and you specify a ordered base $\beta=(v_{1},\dots,v_{n})$ then you have a linear isomorphism $\phi_\beta:V\rightarrow R^n$ that sends $v_i$ to $e_{i}.$

Combining previous you get the following.

If $T:V\rightarrow W$ is linear and you choose basis $\beta=(v_{1},\dots,v_{n})$ and $\gamma=(w_{1},\dots,w_{m})$ in $V$ and $W$ respectively. Then by 3 you have pair of linear isomorphisms $\phi_\beta:V\rightarrow R^n$ and $\phi_\gamma:W\rightarrow R^m.$ Consider linear transformation $F:R^n\rightarrow R^m$ defined by the formula $F=\phi_\gamma\circ T\circ\phi_\beta^{-1}.$ From 1 there exist exactly one matrix $A$ such that $Ax=\phi_\gamma\circ T\circ\phi_\beta^{-1}x.$ (You just has to compute the A) Now by 2 you get that $L_A=\phi_\gamma\circ T\circ\phi_\beta^{-1}.$ I left arguments due to the fact that now we are only working with linear transformations. Sinsce $\phi_\beta$ is an isomorphism we get that
$$L_A\circ\phi_\beta=\phi_\gamma\circ T.$$

Comment: Thanks for answer. How should I understand $\phi_{\beta}^{-1}$? Can you give an example maybe?

Comment: It is invers to $\phi_\beta.$ Since $\phi_\beta$ takes vector in $v$ and returnes sequence of scallars corresponding to $v_i,$ hence $\phi^{-1}$ takes $X=(x_1,\dots,x_n)=x_1e_1+\dots+x_ne_n$ and returnes $x_1v_1+\dots+x_nv_n.$ Example could be taken from your post where $\phi_{\beta}$ is given. Take a series of numbers $X=(1,3,5,9).$ Then $\phi_\beta^{-1}X=1+3x+5x^2+9x^3.$

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. So let's say I choose $(1,3,5,9)$. Then We have $\phi_{\beta}^{-1} = 1+2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3$. Then $\phi_{\gamma}(T(1+3x+5x^2 +9x^3)) = \phi_{\gamma}(3+10x + 27x^2) = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 10 \\ 27 \end{pmatrix}$. Correct right? But how does that equal $L_A$ now? Can you help me out with that?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out =)

Comment: When you have matrix $A\in M(n\times m)$ then you can define linear transformation $L_A:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ in following way $L_A(x)=Ax,$ where on the right side you have just product of matrix and $x$ treated as column vector (generally when we are just in $R^n$ I do not bother wether it is colum vector or row vector. I wrote (1,3,5,9) just so. But when we multiply matrices it matters). It gives you proper definition of $L_A.$ You just computed right hand side. Let's do left... Oh good.

Answer (score 1):

First let's write the domain and codomain of the relevant maps. I'll write $\mathbb{P}_n$ for the space of polynomials of degree at most $n$.

$$T : \mathbb{P}_3 \to \mathbb{P}_2 \\
\phi_\beta : \mathbb{P}_3 \to \mathbb{R}^4 \\
\phi_\gamma : \mathbb{P}_2 \to \mathbb{R}^3 \\
A : \mathbb{R}_4 \to \mathbb{R}^3.$$

The equality

$$A=\phi_\gamma \circ T \circ \phi_\beta^{-1}$$

can be thought of as the definition of the equality

$$A=[T]_\beta^\gamma.$$

That is, this equality can be read as follows. The map $A$ proceeds in these steps:

1. Given a vector $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$, map to the polynomial $p \in \mathbb{P}_3$ defined by $p(y)=x_0 + x_1 y + x_2 y^2 + x_3 y^3$, as described by the basis $\beta$. In other words, apply $\phi_\beta^{-1}$ to $x$.
2. Map $p$ to its derivative $p'$. In other words, apply $T$ to $\phi_\beta^{-1} x$.
3. Map $p'$ to its representation in the basis $\gamma$. In other words, apply $\phi_\gamma$ to $(T \circ \phi_\beta^{-1}) x$.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but what do you mean with $\phi_{\beta}^{-1}$. That's not an inverse is it? Is the composition $\phi_{\gamma} \circ T \circ \phi_{\beta}^{-1}$ a matrixproduct?

Comment: $\phi_{\beta}^{-1}$ is the inverse of $\phi_\beta$. $\phi_\gamma$ is also invertible although I don't need its inverse here. The composition is technically not a matrix product, because we haven't chosen matrix representations for the maps in question. Choosing matrix representations would be circular, because the whole point of this exercise is to define matrix representations of linear transformations on finite dimensional spaces. We're dealing with the *example* of $T : \mathbb{P}_3 \to \mathbb{P}_2$, but we can do the same with any linear map between any two finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: Exactly. When you decide what basis in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $\mathbb{P}^3$ are interesting for you, the whole problem lies in computing the $A.$ Rest is just pure linear algebra and understanding the correspondace between linear transformations and matrices.